# How can I load the large amount of data to datatable without affecting performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, datatables

this script is working fine when i am loading less data(300 rows). But when i try to load more data(3000 rows) it's taking more time and browser showing some script slow down error. Please help me out to resolve this issue

HTML Table as shown below

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="db_new_table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Key </th>
           <th> Value </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         //to here loading data from js     
     </tbody>
</table>
```

My JS Script Looks like below

```
//Intializing database
    var table_new = $('#db_new_table').DataTable({            
      "bSortClasses": false,           
      "lengthMenu": [ 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 ],
      "pageLength": 500,
      "deferLoading": coutnt,            
    });


//Loading data to datatable   
var j=1;        
$.each((this.data), function(i, key){  
  var tr = '<tr class="table_row" data-id='+j+'> <td>'+ i +'</td> <td>'+ key +'</td> </tr>'; 

  table_new.rows.add($(tr)).draw();            
  j++;
});
```

Comment: You should use ajax, instead to load 3k in one call, load only the data that should be visibile.

Comment: Is server side processing an option? If so you can find here an example: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html . Making a simple pagination and only manipulating the dom with 10/25/50 rows can give a performance boost too since dom manipulation is the slowest here.

Comment: According to your description that sounds like all 3000 rows are being inserted into the DOM immediately, which has some impact on the performance. What you could do is try to fetch 300 rows and display those in the visible area, if the user has reached the last row entry (scrolled to the end of your list) you'd trigger a second call to fetch additional 300 rows... and so on. What you also could try is to reuse the existing elements instead of adding new one to the DOM.

Comment: Can you share me any reference regarding what you mentioned  @RamizWachtler

Comment: I'm not sure if there are some relevant/reliable jQuery/JS resources for that (just checked "jquery/javascript lazyload list", I've briefly checked the DataTables forums (which also suggest server-side processing as @peter already pointed out). The hard way would be to implement your custom solution, the easy way to use service-side processing.

Comment: @PavanGS server side datatable is the only option from jquery to do that. but if you chose server side datatable, then you have to handle sorting, searching, pagination all from code side.

Answer (score 1):

3000 rows is quite a lot of DOM elements for browser to process. You can try using virtual scroll to prevent browser slowing or crash. Virtual scroll will only render DOM element which you see in your screen and replace data when you scroll, not add more DOM element.

You can try this library for virtual scroll
https://clusterize.js.org/

In case your request take too much time, you may got timeout problem. In that case you can consider use paging or endless scroll